# virus warning for the latest phpmyadmin (HTML.Exploit.CVE_2014_0322)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I run PHPMyAdmin locally, and after ClamXav updated its definitions today, I get a virus warning whenever I load PHPMyAdmin. The virus name is: HTML.Exploit.CVE_2014_0322.

It boils down to a call to /js/get_scripts.js.php, which loads a bunch of local JavaScript files in one request.

If I edit this script to prevent it from loading JavaScript, the virus warning goes away.

I'm on a Mac, and HTML.Exploit.CVE_2014_0322 is an exploit for Internet Explorer on Windows, so it seems to be a false warning.

I upgraded PHPMyAdmin to the latest version, and still get this error.
Does anyone know which JavaScript file is triggering the error?

Comment: Considering that your JS file could be viewed on any platform, it doesn't make any difference what YOU are running.  You're getting the warning because there really IS something wrong with that JS file.  Also, PHPMyAdmin is for database administration.  So reinstalling that means nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly a false positive.

I run regular scans with clamav on webroots for a number of customers. We got tons of HTML.Exploit.CVE_2014_0322 detections today, mostly these were minified versions of jquery.

Seems ClamAV added some detection rule that generates lots of false alarms. The only thing you can do is wait for ClamAV to fix their Virus database.